# Automate SAS program for different sites using %include

Tags: automation, sas, sas-macro

The problem I have is, I use the same program for reports on multiple sites. I have to run the code for each of them individually. I'm looking to automate my process to call the code and run for all sites in a go. This is the code I tried using but it is not working.

```
data _null_;
array sites {2} _temporary_ (SiteA SiteB);

do k = 1 to dim(sites);
    %let site = sites(k);

    %include '...path\SitesWait.sas';

end; run;
```

The code in SiteWait works perfectly on its own. I defined a macro variable called site, which sets the site for the code to run.

The error I keep getting is 'ERROR 117-185: There was 1 unclosed DO block.'

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. I assume that you have to pass some parameter, otherwise the program is just running a bunch of times.

Comment: The only parameter to pass is 'site', which will be used in the program SitesWait.sas

Comment: Create a macro and pass Sites as parameters

Comment: That code doesn't do that. You want a macro and to use CALL EXECUTE or DOSUBL. There is a fully worked example in the documentation for CALL EXECUTE that will illustrate the usage.

Comment: So the code in your %INCLUDE file is just the middle of a DATA step?

Comment: What is a SITE?  Is it a different computer that you are running the program on?  A different sub directory on the same computer? Something else?  Does the included code refer to the macro variable SITE?  How do you intend to set the macro variable SITE?  Are you talking about the SAS license? The CPU id? Something else?

Comment: Site is a name for different facilities that a report is created for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include another multi-step program into the middle of a DATA step.  `%include` just puts lines from the file into the program stream as if the lines had been typed into program.  When SAS sees the first DATA or PROC statement in the included file it will stop compiling the DATA step in your main program and run it.  That is why your DO loop is not seeing the END statement.

You could just use a data step to generate code that sets the parameter and includes the program.

```
data _null_;
  length site $20 ;
  do site='SiteA','SiteB' ;
    call execute(cats('%nrstr(%let) site=',site,';'));
    call execute("%include '...path\SitesWait.sas';");
  end;
run;
```

What you have created is basically a macro with a single parameter named SITE. In fact you could possible just use %INCLUDE as the body of the macro definition. Then you could just code the calls you want instead of trying to process some list of values.

```
%macro siteswait(site);
%include '...path\SitesWait.sas';
%mend;
%siteswait(SiteA)
%siteswait(SiteB)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you wish to include different files based on prior dataset. I suggest you create the file instead of reading it from array, but keeping with the spirit of your initial request:

```
%let basePath= c:\foo;

data _NULL_;
    array sites {2} $5. ('SiteA' , 'SiteB');

    do k = 1 to dim(sites);
        site = sites(k);
        call execute('%nrstr(%put &basePath.\'||site||';)');
    end;
run;
```

This produces

> c:\foo\SiteA
>
> c:\foo\SiteB

You can easily replace the %put command with `%include` to accomplish what you wish.

**Edit**: What I suggest you try to do instead is something like this:

```
data includes;
    format path $30. file $10.;
    input path $ file $;
    cards;
    c:\foo\ file1.sas
    c:\foo\ file2.sas
    c:\Bar\ file1.sas
    c:\Bar\ file2.sas
; run;

data _null_;
    set includes;
        call execute('%nrstr(%put '||strip(path)||''||strip(file)||';)');
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this :

```
main.sas

%macro ProcessList;
    %let list_of_site=SiteA|SiteB|SiteC;
    %let k=1;
    %do %while (%qscan(&list_of_site, &k,|) ne );
        %let site = %scan(&list_of_site, &k,|);
        %include 'H:\desktop\SAS\test_inc.sas';
        /*%put site=&site;*/
        %let k = %eval(&k + 1);
    %end;


%mend ProcessList;
%processList;


test_inc.sas

%put site=&site;
```

Result:

```
site=SiteA
site=SiteB
site=SiteC
```

With a macro fonction it is simple. You can replace %include with %put.

You can get the list of site from a dataset with this technic :

```
data test;
infile datalines dsd;
   input site : $200. ;
   datalines;
SiteA,
SiteB,
SiteC,
SiteD,
SiteE,
SiteF,
; 
run;

proc sql noprint;
   select quote(trim(site), "'") into : list_of_site separated by "|" from work.test;
quit;
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If the sites don't change often, and if there are not too many of them, this *may* be the simplest approach:

```
%let site=siteA;
%include '...path\SitesWait.sas';

%let site=siteB;
%include '...path\SitesWait.sas';

%let site=siteC;
%include '...path\SitesWait.sas';
```

Be careful though.  You may want to include code at the top of SitesWait.sas that 'resets' you SAS session.  ie. clears any macro values you plan on using, deletes any datasets in your work folder etc.  Otherwise the second call to `SitesWait.sas` may be affected by the prior run.